# How can I use an image as an alpha layer in PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm looking to use a set of images that are white where color should be, black where it should be transparent, and gray in between, to generate patterns as PNGs in PHP. Is there any way to do this? I'm running PHP 5.4 if it helps.

Comment: You can.  Are you using GD, ImageMagick, or something else?

Comment: @Brad I'm using built-in PHP libraries: methods like `imagepng`

Comment: That would be a GD function.

Comment: @Brad it'd be nice if you provided an answer, then!